# Where should someone put the static files such as CS, JS and images in the Codeigniter folder structure?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically in the html file, I would like to include static files as follows:

```
  <link href='css/my.css' type="text/css"/> 
  <link href='js/my.js' type="text/javascript"/> 

  ...
  <img src="image/logo.jpg" />
```

In order to accomplish what I stated above, where should those static files need to go in the Codeigniter folder structure.

Comment: I like to put them outside it. May or may not be the wisest thing to do though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no real answer here, but what I use as best practice for CI projects is the following structure:

```
- assets
-- css
-- js
-- images
- system
-- <all CI folders here>
```

Answer (score 9):

It all comes down to personal preference, I used to have a folder called 'assets' in the root directory alongside 'application' and 'system' but these days I prefer creating a folder called 'public' as it's more semantic.

It doesn't matter where you store them really, pick a name that means something to you.