# Where to put js files in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should someone put the static files such as CS, JS and images in the Codeigniter folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072479/where-should-someone-put-the-static-files-such-as-cs-js-and-images-in-the-codeig)

I have few JavaScript files in my codiginter project. Currently the js files are in a direcotry in the app root. I call the js files by `"../js/jq.js"`. Is it right way to include js files?
or
Where to put my own javascript files in the codigniter directory structure???

What is the best practices???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this similar question:-

[Where should someone put the static files such as CS, JS and images in the Codeigniter folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072479/where-should-someone-put-the-static-files-such-as-cs-js-and-images-in-the-codeig)